# Movimentar Celula de um GridView C# desktop

Tags: c#, .net

Este código faz nada mais que a movimentação de uma linha selecionada em um *datagridview*.

*btnup* -> joga a linha selecionada para cima.
*butndown* -> joga a linha selecionada para baixo.

DÚVIDA: A minha dúvida é, como movimentar somente a célula selecionada, e não a row(linha) inteira.

https://pastebin.com/y4iHHs13

obs:Postei o codigo no pastebin para ficar mais limpo a pergunta.

Comment: Deixe o código na pergunta mesmo, o site recomenda isso.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969753/move-datagridview-selected-cell-row-up-down-on-keys-press-using-c-sharp acho que isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolvido!